# Integral of product of 3 bessel functions

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I am trying to find an analytical form (if any) of the following integral:
$$
\xi_{n,m}(a,b,c) =\int_0^\infty k^n\, j_1(ak)\, j_1(bk)\, j_m(ck)\mathrm{d}k,
$$
where $a$, $b$ and $c>0$ and $j_n$ is the n-th spherical Bessel function.

I have found this link http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/SphericalBesselJ/21/02/02/0005/ that seem to give a solution in the range of my problem. However, I don't understand how to read this formula.

I have already tried unsuccessfully to solve it using a symbolic computation program (Mathematica) but the answer didn't come out.

Can anyone decipher the formula given in the link above or has anyone a knowledge about this integral?

UPDATE:
the answer seem to come from
$$
\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha-1}j_\lambda(a t) j_\mu(b t) j_\nu(c t)\mathrm{d}t = \frac{2^ {\alpha-4}b^\mu c^{-\alpha-\lambda-\mu}\pi^{3/2}\Gamma\left[\frac{\alpha+\lambda+\mu+\nu}{2}\right]}{\Gamma[\lambda +3/2]\Gamma[\mu+3/2]\Gamma\left[\frac{3-\alpha-\lambda-\mu+\nu}{2}\right]}F_{0,1,1}^ {2,0,0}
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    \frac{\alpha+\lambda+\mu+\nu}{2},\frac{\alpha+\lambda+\mu-\nu-1}{2};;;\\
    ;\lambda +\frac{3}{2};\mu+\frac{3}{2};
  \end{matrix}\ \ \
\frac{a^2}{c^2},
\frac{b^2}{c^2}
\right)
$$
My issue being now that I don't understand the $F_{0,1,1}^ {2,0,0}$ notation.

Comment: You need to read about the generalized hypergeometric functions.

Comment: Do you have any link that might point to a solution?

Comment: Yours does. You won't find simpler.

Comment: I do see that, but I haven't found any link that uses the same notation as the link I gave for the hypergeometric functions. All the links I found were using the notation ${}_pF_q(a_1,\cdots,a_p; b_1,\cdots,b_q; x)$.

Comment: You could try Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, fifth edition, p 717, 6.578.

Comment: Looks more like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamp%C3%A9_de_F%C3%A9riet_function

Comment: I would recommending reading about the method of brackets for evaluating definite integrals: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.3356.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2062.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Appell's hypergeometric function $F_4$. You can check this integral in Bailey, Proc.London.Math.Soc.$\mathbf{40}$ 37(1936). Unfortunately it doesn't help much even if you know this analytical result since this function is very complicated... Wolfram quoted this result without any further explanation. This function seems not included in their program either. I already sent them an email to ask them to do so.

Comment: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1112/plms/s2-40.1.37
You can read the paper on this link.